# CLASSIC ASP - SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I'm trying to make a connection to a SQL Server Express DB on localhost, but I get the following error message:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (0x80004005)
>
> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or
> access denied.

The code I'm using is

```
Dim connection 
Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.connection") 
connection.connectionString = "server=localhost;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=RiskManagement;Initial Catalog=RiskManagement;User ID=sa;Password=myPass;" 
connection.Open()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to always check is that you have configured SQL Server to allow remote connections.

[How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

For generic SQL Server Connectivity Troubleshooting consult the following [Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/09/30/SQL-Server-2005-Remote-Connectivity-Issue-TroubleShooting.aspx)

Comment: +1 adding an exception to the firewall for program sqlservr.exe worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue, when I investigated around the network connectvity then I come to know from application server (example Windows `10.10.10.10` or AppServer) is unable to connect database server (Like DBServer or `10.10.10.11`). So once check whether it's pinging from the application server, where application is hosted or located.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue because ESET firewall was on.
I installed an update of a VB6 program. The new .exe had to be entered into the firewall