# Error connecting to a SQL Server from a classic ASP app migrated on W2K12R2

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic, iis-8.5

I'm migrating a classic ASP/.Net hybrid app to IIS 8.5 on W2K12R2.

My credentials work fine when using the *ODBC Data Sources* application (both 32 and 64 bits). It also works fine in the .Net portion of the app.

But in classic ASP, I get a

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

error when using the following connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=sql.example.com;Initial Catalog=mydb;
Persist Security Info=True;User ID=foo;Password=bar
```

I tried using a system DSN configured using the 32 bits version of *ODBC Data Sources*. The error is then

> SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

The app pool of the app is set to Classic mode, 32 bits.

I'm using SQL authentication, not Windows authentication.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CLASSIC ASP - SQL Server does not exist or access denied](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1410021/692942)

Comment: Is it possible you have an issue with DNS resolution to `sql.example.com` *(I know this is just an example address but the point still remains)*?

Comment: I am able to do a connection from the same machine from .Net and ODBC Data Sources, so DNS resolution is ok and the SQL Server is accepting connections from my server.

Comment: Problem is there are 101 things it could be as the question just isn't specific enough, you mention it works with .Net and ODBC but not what those specific configurations are. It could be related to the transport being used *(named pipes, tcpip etc)*, it could be permissions, it could umpteen different things, you need to supply more information if you don't what half cocked guesses.